# navbar-nav gets pushed below navbar-brand?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When the width of my screen reaches 767px, the navigation collapses as excepted.  When I go to 768px, the navbar-nav goes below the navbar-brand.  It is not until I reach 795px, that the navbar-brand and navbar-nav line up again.  These values change depending on how large your navigation is.  Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/leceyelita/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your navbar is too wide so there is not enough space for it to stay on the same line. You could reduce the padding of ".nav > li > a" to

```
padding: 10px 13px;
```

to avoid the problem

Comment: How did you come up with 10px 13px?  Will this change if I add or remove menu items?  Is it also possible to use a media query?

Comment: I just tested using the Chrome console. But it will only work with this set of elements, if you add some the problem will be back since the menu will be wider.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the cause or not, but try taking some of the padding off of your list items. I believe it's just too wide to fit into that spot on the page at that window size.

Answer (score 1):

The total width of .navbar-header and .navbar-nav is 794px and there is no space for them in the same row. You can change padding for .nav>.li>a  to 10px 13px

Comment: How do you determine 10px and 13px?  Is it possible to use a media query as well?

Comment: Default padding for this element - 10px 15px. I opened your link, set 768px width for Output window and used Chrome Developer Tools for change padding. With my values all element stood up in one line.
You can set it as default value or set in media query for problem window width.
However, note that the width of .navbar-nav depends on the links texts. If it will be longer, it will be necessary to reduce the value more. And if it will be shorter you can forgot about this problem.